# Should we specifically ask all of the questions that were proposed on the area51 site during the definition phase?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I see lots of questions in the [Area51 Emacs proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/76571?phase=definition) that have not yet been asked:

Should we go ahead and ask all of those questions? Or at least ask the really interesting ones?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have that question, you are certainly welcome to go ahead and ask it. But there's nothing about the Area 51 process that obligates us to mechanically copy those questions over here. I just wouldn't start "asking" too many questions you're not legitimately interested in the answer to.

[**Asking the First Questions**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/area-51-asking-the-first-questions/)